# Issue with Handling textfield finish editing notification

Tags: iphone, notifications, uitextfield

i'm using notification center to get notified on uitextfield finished editing, here is my code...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification  object:nil];
```

and my function...

```
-(void)textFieldChange:(id)sender{
UITextField *my=(UITextField *)sender; // NOT WORKING

    if([my.text length]==0){
        UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Please Fill This" message:@"This Field Can Not be Kept Empty!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil, nil];


    [myAlert show];

                              }
}
```

what is wrong in this? , i feel sender is not getting type casted in textfield!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know when the Uitextfield will finish editing ,then you can check it by below code my friend..

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

and if you want to check it using NSNotification, then try to send your textfield object in object parameter while calling -(void)textFieldChange:(id)sender method, don't send nil

i am not 100% sure about this but you can try,

let me know is it working or not

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: but if i have to give object as a parameter then i have to use multiple notifications for each textfields, thts y i kept it as nil and trying to type casting of sender.

Comment: so try to use first option that i have told you , it will work for any number of textfields my friend..- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField